# is not JSON serializable - django social auth Facebook login

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm trying to login with Facebook with Django-Social-Auth
But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError at /complete/facebook/
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 25, 22, 20, 14, 665216, tzinfo=<UTC>) is not JSON serializable
```

This is my login template:

```
<a href="{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}">Login with FB</a>
```

My settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'
SOCIAL_AUTH_UID_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_NONCE_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_SERVER_URL_LENGTH = 16
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATION_HANDLE_LENGTH = 16

SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('facebook')
```

Comment: Recent update to Django 1.6? Try changing the session serialization setting back to pickle.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you should just add

```
 SESSION_SERIALIZER='django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

to settings

Comment: As pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300876/django-allauth-session-json-serializable-error-after-login, setting the serializer to PickleSerializer is not without risks